# Controlling User creation in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin, django-authentication

I have a model with a OneToOneField to the django.contrib.auth.models.User.

*e.g.*

```
class Client(models.Model):
    fancy_field = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    user = models.OneToOneField(django.contrib.auth.models.User, primary_key=True)
```

Is there a way to create the corresponding Client when using the Django admin interface to create a new User. I am aware that I could alternatively add Client to the admin interface and customize it to create the User, but since the code is already in place the other way around, I was wondering if I it was possible to trigger some code on User creation in the admin interface.

Comment: have you considered creating a `post_save` signal, and creating a `Client` object if one does not already exist ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI you should explore whether the new custom user module fits your use case:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user

But the answer is to use signals and it was actually in the docs until 1.5 introduced the new custom user feature.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth//#storing-additional-information-about-users

```
# in models.py

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

# definition of UserProfile from above
# ...

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```